# Cannot cast from Fragment to FragmentListView

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

While several people have asked questions about casting fragments to activities (and how that doesn't work), I couldn't find a fix that worked for me. I'm going through [this tutorial,](http://www.androprogrammer.com/2014/03/create-android-dynamic-view-with.html) and have a main activity that contains two fragments. I'm probably missing something fairly obvious:

There error I get: Cannot cast from Fragment to FragmentListView (line18)

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FragmentListView.OnSiteSelectedListener{

Fragmentwebview web;
FragmentListView list;
FragmentManager manager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    manager = getFragmentManager();
    list = (FragmentListView) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
    list.setRefrence(this);
}

@Override
public void onSiteSelected(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    web = (Fragmentwebview) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    // Check for landscape mode
    if (web!= null && web.isVisible())
    {
        web.setNewPage(i);
    }
    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this , FragmentSupport.class);
        intent.putExtra("index", i);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.numeraid.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.numeraid.FragmentSupport"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_support" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.numeraid.FragmentListView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fragment_list_view" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.numeraid.Fragmentwebview"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fragmentwebview" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

The first fragment that's causing the error

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ListView 
    android:name="com.example.NumerAid.list"
    android:id="@+id/list" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: Adding FragmentListView class

```
   package com.example.numeraid;

   import android.R.string;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.ListView;

   public class FragmentListView extends Fragment implements    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
   {
   ListView list;
   String [] websites = {"Google","Facebook","Twitter","Xda-developer"};


   OnSiteSelectedListener SiteListener;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlistview, container, false);
   list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
   list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1));
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return v;
    }

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long l)
{
    SiteListener.onSiteSelected(position);
}

// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnSiteSelectedListener {
    public void onSiteSelected(int i);
}

public void setRefrence(OnSiteSelectedListener siteListener)
{
    this.SiteListener = siteListener;
}

}
```

Comment: Simple answer: Your `FragmentListView` is not a `Fragment`.

Comment: @user3739849 thanks for the reply, what changes should I make?

Comment: I'm still stuck. (Partial) code for FragmentListView is as follows: 'package com.example.numeraid;

 
public class FragmentListView extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
    ListView list;
 String [] websites = {"Google","Facebook","Twitter","Xda-developer"};
  
  
 OnSiteSelectedListener SiteListener;
 
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 }
... 

}'

Comment: My guess is that your `FragmentListView` class extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`. If you want to use the support version, then you should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`. Otherwise, you need to extend `android.app.Fragment` everywhere as done in the tutorial you are following.

Comment: @corsair992 Sorry for not including this, but here are my imports. I was trying to stay within the char limit. Also, I read about getSupport, but it caused another error. 'package com.example.numeraid;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
 
public class Fragmentwebview extends Fragment {'

Comment: You should edit the question to include the `Fragment` class contents, instead of trying to add them in the comments, which have limited space and no formatting. In any case, we need to see the imports of your `FragmentListView`, not `Fragmentwebview`.

Comment: I do have appcompat_v7 as a library, does that make a difference?

Comment: No, the appcompat library shouldn't have anything to do with `Fragment` API.

Comment: whoops, noticed the support.v4.app.Fragment. I think that solved it, so now I'm going to focus on the "The method setReference(MainActivity) is undefined for the type FragmentListView" error that just popped up. Now I need to figure out how to mark @corsair992's answer as best...

Comment: I have only posted comments on your question, so there is no way for you to mark my solution as accepted. If you like, you can post it yourself as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @corsair for this answer, originally posted as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744684/cannot-cast-from-fragment-to-fragmentlistview#comment38395997_24744684):

> My guess is that your `FragmentListView` class extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`
>   instead of `android.app.Fragment`. If you want to use the support version, then you should
>   use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`. Otherwise, you need to
>   extend `android.app.Fragment` everywhere as done in the tutorial you are following.